# Exclude PictureBox From TransparencyKey

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, transparency, picturebox

I have a form set TransparencyKey = Color.White, backColor = Color.White and a PictureBox in it with an image that has a white portion. Is it possible not to make the PictureBox to have transparent on the white portion?

See Image
[image]

Any alternative solution if that's not possible..

Comment: When writing a Windows desktop application, why does everyone think that transparency is the solution? WinForms doesn't really support transparency, and there's little reason for it to do so.

Comment: You got 16 million colors to choose from and you picked the *one* that didn't work.  How did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

If this needs to be WinForms:

Either change the text to 255,255,254 or change the transparency key. I recommend using magenta (255,0,255) for transparency, since that is a color you are unlikely to need to display otherwise.

If you could use WPF:

WPF supports more than just on/off transparency. You can use transparency with gradients, antialiasing and the like. All you need to do is set the AllowsTransparency property on the Window to true, and use a transparent/semitransparent for the Window background.

I think the best way in your case would be to have the Window's background transparent, and place controls on top of it. You could also use a 32bpp PNG image, since that supports the full range of transparency.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. everyone says WPF from chat also.. so i think, i need to try WPF.. anyway, thanks sir..